# How to create a Windows service that start and stops multiple 'exe's/'bat's

Tags: c#, windows, service

I am trying to create a Windows service that will managing starting multiple `exe`s/`bat` files.

So far I have followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer#install-the-service) and am able to start an exe with the following code. But when I stop the service the spawned exe seems to be detached and I'm not sure how to kill it programatically.

Eventually I'd like to start and stop many different `bat`s and `exe`s.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SomeService
{
  public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
  {

    public Service1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
      Process.Start("C:\\Users\\JohnnySmalls\\SomeProgram\\bin\\theExe.exe");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
      // Need to close process, I don't have a reference to it though
      // Process.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Process.Start()` returns a Process object. Store it, then `.CloseMainWindow()` (also with Console things) or `.Kill()` it. I doubt `.Close()` will work.

Comment: @Jimi thank you that seemed to do the trick! Still looking for feedback if I am using the proper pattern to start/stop multiple exes/bats.

Comment: It will work but it's probably not the best approach. See this CodeProject: [Subverting Vista UAC in Both 32 and 64 bit Architectures](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-and-bit-Archite). It has some useful informations. It's old, some considerations don't apply anymore, but you can find some intersting stuff. See the main function here: [CreateProcessAsUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw)

Comment: I don't need to subvert the UAC or show a GUI.

Comment: No, you don't. I told you it's old. It's about the CreteProcessAsUser function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.ServiceProcess;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Timers;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace SomeService
    {

      public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
      {
        private List<Process> _processes;
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _processes = new List<Process>();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
          var process = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\JohnnySmalls\\SomeProgram\\bin\\theExe.exe");
          _processes.Add(process);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
          // Need to close process, I don't have a reference to it though
          // Process.Close();
            foreach(var process in _processes) {
                process.Close();
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can use the following properties 

StandardError - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror?view=netframework-4.8

StandardOutput - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=netframework-4.8

ExitCode - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode?view=netframework-4.8